# How can I open the history list in FoxIt Reader?

Tags: foxit-reader

Dears,

How can I open/find the list of PDF file which is registered in below:

HKCU\Software\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader X.X\Preferences\History

BR. Loghman

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most-recently-used list is actually in registry key
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Foxit Software\Foxit PDF Reader\Continuous\MRU\File MRU`,
although the syntax is less useful, since a string is added before
the file-paths.

From Reader, the MRU is accessed via the menu
*File > Open > Recent Documents*.